# How do I add another user to my Quantcast account?

Tags: account-management

I have a Quantcast account that I'd like to allow other users to log in and modify.  I can't seem to find any way to do this.  Can I add another user, or do we all have to share login credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that I have seen available is allowing access to Hidden Data (View Only) from Settings -> User Privileges

So in order to modify, what little there seems to be able to modify, you would have to share the login details.